# How can I showcase an Ionic2 app on a website?

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

In the [Ionic Component Dokumentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/) you can see an live example off an app. How can I achieve that for my own Ionic2 application, on my own website without writing new JavaScript code, only for the demo?

The switch for the iOS, Android and Windows version would be nice, but is not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to show your development in a website, Ionic recently added a browser build target that generates a Web app. If you run `ionic build browser`, you'll see that Ionic creates a www folder containing assets you can deploy to a web server.

Comment: Yes but as far as I know, that will generate a full page web application. I'm searching for an frame solution, just like that one in the documentation.

Comment: They're using an iframe to load the content inside of the page: `<iframe id="demo-ios" src="/dist/preview-app/www/?production=true&amp;ionicplatform=ios" frameborder="0"></iframe>`